# In flex How to Show the error textArea...when mouse is scrolled

Tags: apache-flex, scroll

in my flex application im using a text area which shows fields name when the mandatory fileds are not provided by users.....my application has about 30 fields...im showing the textarea on top...so its hard to see the text area when i SCROLL down the mouse...
i need to show the TEXTAREA along when i SCROLL DOWN THE MOUSE....(it should show in side nearear to scroll button)....
Thankxxx:-)

Comment: so, what I think you want is a text area that shows the fields that hasn't been filled in yet?  Is it to be only displayed when the user tries to submit? Are you using validators?

Comment: not using validations in flex frontend....validating the fields in java backend process....the displayed text error area should come along with the scroll bar in side of the screen....tats it!

Comment: Why aren't you using front-end validation as well?  Flex has a whole validation framework at your disposable.  Frankly, for your question itself, there are hundreds of ways to doing it without having more information on specifications of the interaction, styling, etc.

Comment: yeah You are Rite  J_A_X ...but...my project requirement is changing jsp to flex...java code im using the existing code..so not to change the flow..i left the validation part as it was in the java code!!:-) i hope you got it!!

Comment: I do, but I'm still lost on your actual question.  Is it that every time you try to submit a form, you send to the server which returns data to say which field is in bad form?  What's the structure of that data? how to do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: yeah...each and every time if i try to submit a form, i send to the server which returns data to say which field is in bad form....oops!is there any prob in tat??..

Comment: ... Okay seriously, I'm just going to stop even trying to help you if you can't give me the information I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code I've made to help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application minHeight="600" minWidth="955" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function checkbox_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var text:String = "";
            var numOfControls:int = formContentGroup.numElements;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < numOfControls; i ++)
            {
                var control:CheckBox = CheckBox (formContentGroup.getElementAt(i));
                if (control.selected)
                {
                    text += text.length > 0 ? ", " : "";
                    text += control.label;
                }
            }
            statusText.text = text;
        }

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="contentJustify" />
        </s:layout>
        <s:Group height="400" width="400">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" />
            </s:layout>
            <s:TextArea editable="false" id="statusText"
                includeInLayout="{statusText.text &amp;&amp; statusText.text.length > 0}"
                updateComplete="event.currentTarget.heightInLines = NaN"
                visible="{statusText.text &amp;&amp; statusText.text.length > 0}" />
            <s:VGroup height="100%" id="formContentGroup">
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox1" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox2" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox3" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox4" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox5" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox6" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox7" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox8" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox9" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox10" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox11" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox12" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox13" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox14" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox15" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox16" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox17" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox18" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox19" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox20" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox21" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox22" />
                <s:CheckBox change="checkbox_changeHandler(event)" label="CheckBox23" />
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:Group>
        <s:VScrollBar includeInLayout="{formContentGroup.height &lt; formContentGroup.contentHeight}"
            viewport="{formContentGroup}" visible="{formContentGroup.height &lt; formContentGroup.contentHeight}" />
    </s:Group>

</s:Application>
```

To test it just check or uncheck checkboxes.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: What's wrong with using scrollbar with viewport? What requirements do you have if this isn't the right solution for you?

Comment: it works perfect and i used the same in my application...thankxx man...i jus want to know whether is there anyother way...bcoz am developing another one in flex 3 and i have to meet simillar requirement but little modified..;-)yup!

Comment: Another way which will work both in Flex 3 and Flex 4 is creating custom skin for target container and include your text field in border. In Flex 3 you'll have to provide the right Edge Metrics for that skin. I suppose using scrollbars with viewport is much more simple.